# [@angular/google-maps]: can’t set “className” to customize label marker => MarkerLabel

Tags: angular, google-maps

Currently @angular/google-maps does not allow adding **"className"** to customize the label of a marker.

**It only allows the following options:**

- color
- fontFamily
- fontSize
- fontWeight
- text

[image]

**Question:**
¿How could we add a white border to the text (Label market)?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Turns out I was using the old version of types:
@types/googlemaps

Instead of the new one:
@types/google.maps